# Integral by trigonometric substitution: $ \int \:\frac{2y^3}{\sqrt{1-y^2}}\mathrm dy $

Tags: calculus, integration, substitution

> $$ \int \:\frac{2y^3}{\sqrt{1-y^2}}\mathrm dy $$

I substitute $$ y = \sin t $$ then $$ 2 \int \:\frac{\sin^3 t \cdot \cos t}{\cos t}\;\mathrm dt = 2 \int \sin^2 t\;\mathrm d \cos t $$ 
What should I do next, and how do I convert back to the original variable $y$?

Comment: Why not $$\sin  t=y$$

Comment: Another way: $$\sqrt{1-y^2}=u$$

Comment: $\sin^2t=1-\cos^2t$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$I=2\int\frac{x^3}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\mathrm{d}x$$
$x=\sin u$: 
$$I=2\int\sin^3u\ \mathrm{d}u$$
$$I=2\int(1-\cos^2u)\sin u\ \mathrm{d}u$$
$w=\cos u$:
$$I=2\int(w^2-1)\mathrm{d}w$$
$$I=2\int w^2\mathrm{d}w-2\int \mathrm{d}w$$
$$I=\frac23w^3-2w$$
$$I=\frac23\cos^3u-2\cos u$$
$$I=\frac23(1-x^2)^{3/2}-2(1-x^2)^{1/2}+C$$
$$I=-\frac23(2+x^2)\sqrt{1-x^2}+C$$

Answer (score 4):

This type of problem is much easier if you do a $u-$sub by picking $u=1-y^2$ and $du=-2ydy,$ then

$$\int \frac{2y^3dy}{\sqrt{1-y^2}}=-\int\frac{(1-u)}{\sqrt{u}}du$$
and this becomes a simple power rule computation afterward.

Answer (score 1):

You've established the following relationship.

$$\int{\frac{2y^3}{\sqrt{1-y^2}}dy}=\int{2\sin^2t\space dt}+C$$
Where $C$ is a fixed constant.
You can evaluate the second integral using the rule $$\cos(2\alpha)=1-2\sin^2(\alpha)$$
Then use that $y=\sin t \to t=\sin^{-1}(y)$ to change the integral back.

Answer (score 0):

Though I find the substitution $u=\sqrt{1-y^2}$ leading to the most elegant solution of this integral, you are asking for a help with the integral obtained through the substitution $y=\sin t.$

$$\begin{aligned}\int \:\frac{\sin^3 t \cdot \cos t}{\cos t}\;\mathrm dt& = \int \sin^2 t\;\mathrm d \cos t\\&=\int (1-\cos ^2 t)\;\mathrm d \cos t,\end{aligned}$$ which is easy to finish.
Then use $\:t=\arcsin y\:$ and $\;\cos (\arcsin y)=\sqrt{1-y^2}.$